# ES6 modules not working with babel 6 and gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm trying to understand how to use modules with babel 6 and gulp. I created some test files

**file a.js**

```
export function test () {
    console.log(11111);
}
```

**file app.js**

```
import {test} from 'a.js';
console.log(test());
```

**file gulpfile.babel.js**

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import babel from 'gulp-babel';
import fs from 'fs';
import browserify from 'browserify'
import babelify from 'babelify';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';


gulp.task('default', () => {
    var bundler = browserify('src/app.js');
    bundler.transform(babelify);

    bundler.bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) { console.error(err); })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "babel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

So, it's seems that all is correct, but when I run the `gulp` command, I see this error -  [Error: Cannot find module 'a.js' from 'E:\JS\babel\src']
I cant understand why this error is happened and how to resolve it

Here in the repo on github - https://github.com/zheleznov/ecma-modules.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to a file, you need to provide the **path** to the module file:

```
... from './a.js';
```

Otherwise, Node will look for a module with name "a.js" in `node_modules/`.

This has nothing to do with ES6 btw. That's how Node / browserify works. See the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This one helps :)